# unix : how does a "./process | sort" work?

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, mapreduce, pipe

To debug some map/reduce jobs I often test them using a simple unix command that basically reads

```
cat data/* | mapper | sort | reduce > out
```

Now everything works just fine, but I'm wondering what *really* happens with the `map | sort` command.

More precisely :

- does someone knows how the ram/cpu is loaded by `sort` ?
- Is the `sort` command sorting data *on the fly*, or does it wait for the map  job to be finished ( note that the mapper uses STDOUT and does not wait for the end of the computation to output data) ?
- Using quite a large amount of input data does not seem to load the ram as I would expect ( I rather observe peaks of cpu, but I'm not really measuring this very precisely). Is it possible for the process to use less ram as the amount of output information ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux, `sort` uses merge sort algorithm (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix) ). A merge sort can store some parts in temporary files on disk (and it does in case of `sort`). So the process uses a reasonable amount of RAM (you can specify how much RAM is used via `--buffer-size` option).